# How to lock y movement on CSS grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm new to html and CSS and I'm trying to make a Google-like search bar. If you look at Google's homepage when you resize the window the search bar and the logo move with the resize on the X-axis but they are locked on the Y axis. How do I achieve something like that? Here's my code:

```
.searchbar
{
display: grid;
height: 92.4vh;
border:1px solid green;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
#title
{
color: red;
font-family: 'PT Serif', serif;
font-size: 40px;
grid-row: 2;
grid-column: 2;
align-self: flex-end;
justify-self:center;
text-align: center;
}
#bar
{
grid-row: 3;
grid-column: 2;
justify-self:center;
}
```

Html:

```
<body>
<main>
    <div class="searchbar">
        <div id="title">Title</div>
        <div id="bar"><input type="text" placeholder="Search"></div>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
```

Here's a picture of how I want it:[image]

As you can see the window is resized, the search bar and logo are centered on the X-axis but they stay still on the Y-axis.

Comment: Could you add your html markup and a reference example for what you want?

Comment: @Zachary Haber I edited the question with the info you asked for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's two ways of doing it, I've simplified what was requested by using flexbox instead of grid, as well as just modifying the grid code you had. If you want the location of the elements to remain at the same Y coordinate, you just need to make sure that you use a non-height relative unit.

Since the height of the searchbar is based on the view height (vh), and you were using fr for the grid. The FR uses a fraction of the available free space which is based on the view height.

The flexbox solution to this is pretty easy as you just have to align them together and then put a `margin-top` in to get it to the Y location you want it to stay in.

Modifying your code to work with the grid, is also pretty simple. You just need to change your row definitions to something like: `grid-template-rows: 50px max-content max-content 1fr;` that way it starts off always at the same location. And then you can modify the spacing between the elements using `row-gap`.

```css
.searchbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  height: 92.4vh;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#title {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: red;
  font-family: 'PT Serif', serif;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.searchbar-grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 92.4vh;
  border: 1px solid green;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 50px max-content max-content 1fr;
}

#title-grid {
  color: red;
  font-family: 'PT Serif', serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
  align-self: flex-end;
  justify-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#bar-grid {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 2;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  Flex
  <main>
    <div class="searchbar">
      <div id="title">Title</div>
      <div id="bar"><input type="text" placeholder="Search"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
  Grid
  <main>
    <div class="searchbar-grid">
      <div id="title-grid">Title</div>
      <div id="bar-grid"><input type="text" placeholder="Search"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid responsive when u want your content to retain its place on resize. so for width I used static width while dynamic 25% margin-top.

```
.content {
  max-width: none;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 30%;
  margin-left: 250px;
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n1qjdk

Answer (score 1):

You're over complicating this alignment. You don't need flexbox or even the more advanced css grid to achieve that alignment.

All you need is good old margin: auto;

```
        .searchbar {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 400px;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

        h1 {
            color: red;
            font-family: 'PT Serif', serif;
            font-size: 40px;
            grid-row: 2;
            grid-column: 2;
            align-self: flex-end;
            justify-self: center;
            text-align: center;
        }


        #bar {
            border: 1px solid red;
            display: block;
            margin:0 auto;
        }


    <body>        
        <div class="searchbar">
            <h1>Google</h1>
            <input type="text" id="bar" placeholder="Search">
        </div>        
    </body>
```

If you look at Google's source code you'll see they're using position: absolute to achieve that alignment which is even more basic than flex, grid, and margin.

[When to use flex](https://brolik.com/blog/when-to-use-flexbox/)